# react native flatlist not keeping scroll position when appending to data in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing a infinite scroll list view with the FlatList component in react native. I realized that even before the data gets appended any other prop changes will trigger a re-render of the component and therefore losing the scroll position in the list view.

I don't believe that is normal behavior, does any one know what I should do to have this work with redux ?

Comment: Only a state change will trigger a re-render both in react and react-native. Could you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: it's been a long time, but do you remember what your solution was?